# Creating a tram timetable with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database, nosql

I am trying to create an application which lists tram times for a station to the next. I have been given large amounts of data in an excel spreadsheet. The data consists of Lines (EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH). Each of these lines include a list of stops(stations). Each of the stations consist of a massive list of times from day to night. The system should take a look at current time and render out all lines, stations and times based on many different queries (mainly searching start to end stations).

The excel table is laid out for only ONE line like:

```
Station 1  07:00 07:30 08:50 ...
Station 2  07:15 07:45 08:55 ...
Station 3  07:18 08:00 09:05 ...
```

think of the stations as stops. The distance between the first journey from Station 1 to Station 2 is 15 minutes. Then the next tram from station1 starts at 7:30. There are many of these excel documents represented as lines.

I am using mongoid in rails so my models are like:

```
class Line
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embeds_many :stations

  field :line, type: String
end

class Route
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embedded_in :station

  field :time, type: Time
end

class Station
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embeds_many :routes
  embedded_in :line, inverse_of: :stations 

  field :name, type: String
end
```

A line has many stations, a station belongs to line.

A Station has many routes,a route belongs to station.

I know I can import the excel data as it is large but i am having a little difficulty trying to work with these models. How would I be able to store this data is this way and later query based on my requirement or would I have to create my model like line1, line 2, line 3. or am I right?

Comment: Great to see you keep working on this. Your questions aren't very specific but heads up, your models are just fine. Importing is a matter of a few loops to parse the data, no problem either. Just one thing, rename the filed `line` in your `Line` model to `name`. Much better to understand.

You didn't say what querys you have in mind.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I'm basically trying to query from a station to the next and output all the available times. So essentially I should have the first query which allows me to select two stations (start and end) and retrieve all times within them stations.